# Execute something by default whenever any function is called in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime, time

I have a requirement to know the time at which every function that is called using python. Is there a way this can be done without explicitly using a `time.time()` call when a function is called?

Example:

```
def fn_add(a,b):
    ## print fn call time without explicitly using time.time() 
    return a+b
        
def fn_mult(a,b):
    ## print fn call time without explicitly using time.time()
    return a*b
        
def fn_div(a,b):
    ## print fn call time without explicitly using time.time()
    return a/b
        
def fn_sub(a,b):
    ## print fn call time without explicitly using time.time()
    return a-b
    
print fn_add(1,3)
print fn_mult(1,3)
print fn_div(3,1)
print fn_sub(3,1)
```

Expected Output

```
time : 12345
4
time : 12346
3
time : 12347
3
time : 12348
2
```

Comment: Is it about python-3.x or python-2.7? Please select only relevant tag (do not spam). Possibly the generic `python` tag is sufficient.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing, but maybe a profiler may be sufficient for you (measuring time on every function). Else you can add a decorator to the function you want to call, or you should check how profiler work (so how to graft timer). Note: any solution will slow down sensibly the code (`print` is not cheap, and it requires many resources and call to operating system)

Comment: I have a library which is being worked on by many people. There may be many APIs that are added and it is not possible to ensure every person logs specific prints like time, API name etc, Each time an API is called, I want the API name, time etc to be logged even though it is not intentionally done.